# Accent characters on ubuntu 18.04 works in some softwares but not in others

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, i3-wm, special-characters

I have recently installed a Ubuntu 18.04 and I use i3wm.
My keyboard layout is br abnt2 and it is already configured but I am not been able to use some accented letters in some softwares (textboxes in general) but in others, everything is working fine.
For example, in google chrome, I am able to type accents (ã, á, à, â, etc) but in telegram, KeePassXC, Keepass2, I am not been able to type those accent. This doesn't used to happen in my old ubuntu 16.04 installation. And it is kind of annoying to not been able to simply type an accent the right way.

Do someone knows what is happening? It seems not to be a general ubuntu keyboard configuration issue but something more specific. Maybe a GTK issue? Do someone have a clue to point me in the right direction in order to solve this problem?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en might offer some help here.

Comment: @Graham Thank you for pointing this page but there is no help there for this specific issue. My Ubuntu is really already configured to use special characters and I can even use then in the console. It is everything working fine in the system itself. It is an issue just in some softwares that (for some odd reason) just can't display the accented caracteres. It is not a general issue. For example, when I'm writing a message in Telegram and I type "á", the letter itself is displayed as "a" without the accent, but if I do the same at a text terminal, everything works fine.

Comment: I'm starting to think that that is some kind of Qt issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that some apps like the ones I've mentioned in my question needs ibus to deal properly with the accents so I will post what I did to solve my problem just as a help if someone else gets in the same situation.

I've just put this in my i3 config file:

```
exec --no-startup-id ibus-daemon
```

Additionally, if you are from Brasil assure you have this in your i3 config file too:

```
exec "setxkbmap br"
```

... and assure your /etc/default/keyboard file has the proper keyboard configurations. Mine is like this:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="br"
XKBVARIANT="abnt2"
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

That's it. Everything is working the way it should now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me on Ubuntu 22.04 at [Fedora Discussion: Keyboard layout in Wayland doesn’t work correctly](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/keyboard-layout-in-wayland-doesnt-work-correctly/68832)

```
ibus engine xkb:us:intl:eng
```